# Watched screen recording but it's not saved to the desktop

Tags: macos, quicktime, screen-recording, autosave

I recently recorded a session with my dad. I stopped the recording after the session ended (with the setting set to save to Desktop), clicked the icon that appeared on the lower right corner to open the file, and played back a few minutes to make sure it worked.

I then clicked Share to send it via AirDrop to my computer, which did not work; the status remained "cancelled" despite my efforts. I assumed I'd be able to access it through my phone by sending it through a third app, so I pressed cancel on the AirDrop pop-up window.

The entire screen recording closed and (apparently) vanished forever after the action. I'm extremely frustrated because I can't seem to locate this video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be so much more useful if I could take a picture of taking a picture, but it seems Apple doesn't allow that.

If you go to System Preferences, Keyboard, Screenshots and note the key sequence for Screenshot and recording options, you can use that to record the monitor or portion of the screen, and specify where to save it. Options (which see) include saving to Desktop, Documents, Clipboard, Mail, Messages, Preview, and Other Location…. I suspect you saved your first recording to the clipboard, and the second to the Desktop, but I have no idea how you changed the destination between recordings.

Comment: On your first recording I'm also assuming you have “Show floating thumbnail” in effect, and that's what you were viewing after the first recording.

Comment: Zoya, make sure and accept an answer so someone gets points!

Comment: yes! in that case is there a way to recover/ access files that were set to save on clipboard?? also yes, i pressed the preview that popped up on the lower right corner to view the video

Comment: @zoyaofthebleedingsnow - I'm afraid that if you don't have a clipboard manager (I use the one that comes with [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai)), and if you've replaced the clipboard with another screen capture/selection/etc, there's no way that I know of to recover what was in the clipboard. Any one else know? And thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: before you start the recording, there are options that show up on the screen, and in the options^ drop down, you can set the save location or clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

Check `~/Library/ScreenRecordings/` (the Library folder in your home directory).

Comment: i appreciate the help but i just checked and it wasn't there; nothing was there actually, since all my screenrecordings/screenshots are all set to save on desktop

Comment: Thanks @grg! Found all the screen recordings where I swiped to save rather than Open + Save.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably Dropbox. I had the same problem a while ago, even with screen capture set to save files on my Desktop, they always ended up in a Screenshots folder within Dropbox. Hope this helps.