# I lost screen recording in macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-recording

I recently recorded a session with my dad. I stopped the recording after the session ended (with the setting set to save to Desktop), clicked the icon that appeared on the lower right corner to open the file, and played back a few minutes to make sure it worked.

I then clicked Share to send it via AirDrop to my computer, which did not work; the status remained "cancelled" despite my efforts. I assumed I'd be able to access it through my phone by sending it through a third app, so I pressed cancel on the AirDrop pop-up window.

The entire screen recording closed and (apparently) vanished forever after the action. I'm extremely frustrated because I can't seem to locate this video.

Comment: Is this question the same that [you asked a few weeks ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/420258/88313)?  Do any of those answers help you?

Comment: yes! apparently no, that's why i decided to ask again but in more detail :))

Comment: Asking the same question twice isn't allowed on this site.  You should edit your original question to add the detail instead.

Comment: If the file has not been deleted, it is not gone either ...

Comment: oh sorry i didn't know that. i'll do as you say

Comment: i have no idea if it has been deleted or not, however i've tried recovery softwares and found nothing, unfortunately.